# my site shows white space on right in mobile chrome but not desktop chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

site in progress: http://www.scissormanmusic.com

This is the first site I've made since learning Javascript/Jquery so please be nice to me. I used Bootstrap, Javascript & Jquery to add responsiveness to my site & it works great on FF24 & Chrome30! But when I view this site in portrait mode in the mobile version of Chrome on my Galaxy S3 there's this white space on the right I can't seem to find the cause of. In landscape mode the white space isn't there & the site looks & behaves like it should.

I'm using the following meta tags I thought would keep this problem from happening:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Quite confused as to why it displays differently between the mobile & desktop versions of Chrome! And only in portrait mode!

I'd like to also note that because I've used Javascript/JQuery to make my site responsive, I did not add any @media queries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<table>` tag in your contact form has a `width` attribute of `450`. This is too big given the left margin.

The maximum width for that table should be 415px however you should probably work out a nicer way to achieve that layout using CSS.

Comment: Perhaps using percentages would be great.

Comment: thanks for your replies y'all, but unfortunately removing the width attribute doesn't change a thing. Good idea though! Any other suggestions? Perhaps there's a way to debug mobile chrome like you can using the inspector in desktop chrome?

Comment: @user2731260 you sure you don't just have a cached version? Looks fine now on my Nexus4

Comment: i toggled "request desktop site" and all's well! thanks everyone!

Answer (score 9):

Set the css below for head and body.

```
html, body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Why does this work? I've checked all my containers and there is nothing that is overflowing and yet this works. And if I remove the style using the debugger it still works!